# jQuery $.getJSON() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I'm trying to parse a JSON response, but any instruction in the $.getJSON cannot be executed.

The json.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <script>
            $.getJSON("json.php?jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
               var a = data[0].cve_id + 'something';
            });
            alert(a); //chrome says "a is not defined"
         </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

The json.php:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
echo file_get_contents("http://www.cvedetails.com/json-feed.php?numrows=10&vendor_id=0&product_id=0&version_id=0&hasexp=1&opec=1&opov=1&opcsrf=1&opfileinc=1&opgpriv=1&opsqli=1&opxss=1&opdirt=1&opmemc=1&ophttprs=1&opbyp=1&opginf=1&opdos=1&orderby=1&cvssscoremin=0");
?>
```

Any idea why?

LATER:

Thanks for the replies. I've understood the reason.

I've switched from `$.getJSON` to `$.get`, specifying the `data type` to `json`.

Comment: Your AJAX is asynchronous. Variables have scope.

Comment: At the time `alert(a)` happens, the asynchronous AJAX call has not yet completed.  You need to `alert(a)` inside the `function(data)` callback.  If you need to use the value to modify your DOM, you must do so in the callback

Comment: _chrome says "a is not defined"_ - That's because `a` is defined as a _local_ variable inside the callback function that you pass to `$.getJSON()`, so it can only be accessed inside that function (even aside from the async issue).

Comment: I've also tried `alert(a)` inside `function(data)` and the alert doesen't pop up. Tried also `console.log(a)` and nothing shows up.

Comment: If `alert(a)` inside the function doesn't work that suggests an error on the line before, e.g., if `data` isn't an array with a `0` element then `data[0]` is `undefined` and doesn't have a `cve_id` property. Please show the JSON structure that is retrieved. (Try `console.log(data)` as the _first_ line of the function...)

Comment: as an aside, if you have firebug, you might want to use console.log(a) rather than alert(a). It's not as annoying and gives better debug when you want to inspect objects / arrays. If you've not got firebug, get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**var a** is defined inside the callback closure (anonymous function). One of the main reasons to use closures is that they produce private scope. I.e. any variables defined inside the function will not available to code outside of the function.

This will work:

```
$.getJSON("json.php?jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
    var a = data[0].cve_id + 'something';
    alert(a);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

the JSON call is asynchronous so the callback function dont get dont get called until youre sever returns the data, But the javascript code keeps running to the next line of code. resulting in a stil being undefined try changing it to somthing along the lines of:

```
$.getJSON("json.php?jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
    var a = data[0].cve_id + 'something';
    alert(a)
});
```

you can define other methods outside of the callback and invoke em when the event happens whith the propper data